# EF Core - Query data from server 100 records at a time

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Ok I have this issue that is arising with a program I developed in Angular, with NET 5.0 as backend with EF Core and SQL Server. I have a documents table that is close to 15000 records now, and because this is a web based program and async, when I get to that page it is starting to take way too long for the data to come. I know I could just limit to get me the latest 1000 records or something but what if I wanted to get 100 records and when I go to the next page in the table it downloads the next 100 records and so on.

Is there any way to do this? I have been banging my head against the wall for a whole week trying to see how to solve this, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean like "paging"? For wich a naive approach would be "Skip(X).Take(Y)". But you'd probably want to request N records, starting from the record with ID XYZ to improve on performance.

Comment: See : https://www.michalbialecki.com/2020/09/14/executing-raw-sql-with-entity-framework-core-5/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKj6U4qDmgQ

Comment: Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

Comment: Thank you so much for the help guys, just when i thought I was getting to know shit I realize I do know nothing at all. the beauty of programming

Answer (score 0):

can try something like this to retrieve only a hundred documents for the current page

```
public IActionResult GetDocuments(int page) {
   var pageSize = 100;
   var documents = dbContext.Documents.OrderBy(d => d.Id).Skip((page-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

   return Ok(documents); 
}
```